# It is currently noon (12pm). What is the probability that the hour hand points towards $3$ after infinite hours from now?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I found the following question at Android's Probability Puzzle.

> You have a broken $12$-hour analog clock on your wall; every sixty minutes the hour hand moves forward by one hour with probability $0.99,$ but remains stuck in place with probability $0.01.$ The movements are independent across hours: the probability of move-stuck-m move is $0.99\times 0.01 \times 0.99$, for example.
>
> It is currently noon (12pm). We are interested  in the probability that the hour hand points towards $3$, $N$ hours from now. What does that probability converge to as $N$ goes to infinity?

Given $N$ hours, for the hour hand to reach $3,$ it must move $3$ times and get stuck $N-3$ times with $\binom{N-1}{2}$. So, the probability after $N$ hours is
$$\binom{N-1}{2} \times 0.99^3 \times 0.01^{N-3}.$$
However, if a take $N\to\infty,$ I will get $0$.

The answer given is $\frac{1}{12}.$
May I know what's wrong with my calculations above?

Comment: This is basically a Markov Chain with invariant distribution $(1/12, \ldots, 1/12)$. As for your calculation, what is $\binom{N-1}{2}$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang $\binom{N-1}{2} = \frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{2}$. It is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: The easiest way to reach this answer is by appeal to indifference: There is no reason any hour should be preferred over any other, so all hours should have probability $1/12$.  Not exactly rigorous, but it's more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the answer is $1/12$ is because this is basically a Markov Chain with invariant distribution $(1/12, \ldots, 1/12)$. Convergence to equilibrium is guaranteed from any starting state, because the Chain is aperiodic and positive-recurrent.

The reason your answer is wrong is that the clock can advance $12k+3$ times, while you have only considered the possibility that $k=0$

Comment: I see. I miss out your second paragraph. Can the answer be proven using elementary mathematics instead of using markov chain?